# Post to facebook using Graph API and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, open-uri

I'm playing with facebook Graph API and wanted to post to my timeline using ruby.

While posting using only URL I used

```
 "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/feed?method=POST&access_token=access_token&message=message&link=balhblah.com&actions=%7B%20%22name%22:%22Download%%22,%20%22link%22:%22http://blahblah.com%22%20%7D&name=NAME&caption=caption&description=description"
```

and it worked perfectly. But I want to do that using ruby. So I used

```
open("http://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/feed?method=POST&access_token=access_token&message=message&link=balhblah.com&actions=%7B%20%22name%22:%22Download%%22,%20%22link%22:%22http://blahblah.com%22%20%7D&name=NAME&caption=caption&description=description")
```

but I'm getting OpenURI HTTP Error 400 BAD request. I required 'open-uri' gem also.
Am I doing something wrong? I'm a newbie in ruby

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting directly using https requests to the Facebook API, why not use a library? [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) is a good option. With that, something like this would post on your wall:

```
require 'koala'
@api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
@api.put_wall_post(process_result(fql))
```

You need to `gem install koala` and to setup your `oauth_access_token before` using Koala. Check [Koala's readme](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) for that.

Comment: tried it. But I'm fed up with ssl certificate verification on windows

Comment: I don't think that you'll be able to authenticate on Facebook without SSL. In other words, at least to retrieve the initial OAuth token, you'll need an encrypted connection.